# Why don't zero-dimensional numpy arrays in records support item assignment?

Tags: python, numpy, slice, record

First, a shape `(4,)` numpy array can be assigned:

```
In [33]: a = np.zeros((10,), dtype=[('k', '<u8'), ('t', '<f4'), ('d', np.bool, (4,))])

In [34]: b = np.ones((), dtype=np.bool)

In [35]: a[0][2][3] = b
```

But, a shape `()` cannot if it's in a record:

```
In [36]: a = np.zeros((10,), dtype=[('k', '<u8'), ('t', '<f4'), ('d', np.bool, ())])

In [37]: a[0][2][()] = b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-075e4ba95b60> in <module>()
----> 1 a[0][2][()] = b

TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object does not support item assignment
```

But if it's not in a record, it works just fine:

```
In [38]: a = np.zeros((), np.bool)

In [39]: a[()] = b
```

Why?

---

What a record type looks like:

```
In [4]: a
Out[4]:
array([(0,  0., [False, False, False, False]),
       (0,  0., [False, False, False, False]),
       (0,  0., [False, False, False, False]),
       (0,  0., [False, False, False, False]),
       (0,  0., [False, False, False, False]),
       (0,  0., [False, False, False, False]),
       (0,  0., [False, False, False, False]),
       (0,  0., [False, False, False, False]),
       (0,  0., [False, False, False, False]),
       (0,  0., [False, False, False, False])],
      dtype=[('k', '<u8'), ('t', '<f4'), ('d', '?', (4,))])

In [2]: a
Out[2]:
array([(0,  0., False), (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False),
       (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False),
       (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False)],
      dtype=[('k', '<u8'), ('t', '<f4'), ('d', '?')])
```

Comment: That's not zero length but zero dimensional.  `b` has one item.  I've never experimented with a dtype as in [36].  What does it display like? Access?  What does the () for `a['d']` do for you?   Why not omit it and let the field take 1 item like the rest.

Comment: @hpaulj You're right "zero-dimensional".  The reason I index with `()` is because the index is programatically-generated.  You can try displaying a record type by pasting these lines into ipython.

Comment: I understand the indexing given the definition.  But I'm wondering about definition.  I ask about the display because I'm reading this on a tablet.

Comment: @hpaulj So, for background, I am generating this "history" data structure having an integer key, a floating point time, and an arbitrarily-shaped data.  Usually, the data has vector or matrix shape, but in this case, it has a scalar shape.  The code to update the history is the same for all cases.  I'll edit the question to show what displaying the data structure looks like.

Comment: So it's code generated.  The display tells me something significant - `dtype` has ignored the `()` dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example:

```py
a = np.zeros((10,), dtype=[('k', '<u8'), ('t', '<f4'), ('d', np.bool, (4,))])
```

Creates a 1-dimensional numpy array where each element contains `Tuple(_, _, List[np.bool])`

The index `a[0]` references:

```
(0,  0., [False, False, False, False])
```

Therefore `a[0][2][3]` references the np.bool inside `**` below

```
(0,  0., [False, False, False, **False**])
```

and acts how you expected.

The second example:

```
a = np.zeros((10,), dtype=[('k', '<u8'), ('t', '<f4'), ('d', np.bool, ())])
```

Creates a 1-dimensional numpy array where each element contains `Tuple(_, _, np.bool)` e.g.

```
(0,  0., False)
```

So `a[0][2]` references:

```
(0, 0., **False**)
```

The third index `a[0][2]**[()]**` acts on the np.bool object, which is not indexable.

A simplified example that throws the same error is shown below:

```
a = [False]
a[0] = True    # works
a = True       # changed type from [bool] to bool
a[0] = True    # Fails b/c bools are not scriptable

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Then, why would indexing by `()` work on zero-dimensional numpy array?

Comment: Because `a = np.zeros((), np.bool)` is type `np.array(np.bool))` rather than just a plain `np.bool` and the array is scriptable.

Comment: To me, it seems like a bug in the implementation of numpy records since I specifically asked for a record with shape `()`

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I think it's a bug.  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9442

Comment: it does seem inconsistent that `np.array([], dtype=[('d', 'b', ())]).dtype` drops the shape definition and returns `dtype([('d', 'i1')])` while `np.array([], dtype=[('d', 'b', (1,))]).dtype` keeps it. Combine that with `np.zeros(())` returning with a shape `()` and its pretty counterintuitive!

Comment: `[('d', 'b', 1)]` also drops the shape.  Nothing, (), and 1 are all taken to mean, don't add a dimension to this field.   `(3,)` means add 1 dimension, `(1,3)` means add 2, etc.  What shape snd dtype should `a['d']` have?

Answer (score 1):

```
array([(0,  0., False), (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False),
       (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False),
       (0,  0., False), (0,  0., False)],
      dtype=[('k', '<u8'), ('t', '<f4'), ('d', '?')])
```

Note that `('d', '?')` is the same as though you had defined the field as `('d', np.bool)`.

In my own example

```
In [621]: x = np.ones((3,),dtype=[('f0',int),('f1',int,()),('f2',int,(1,))])
In [622]: x
Out[622]: 
array([(1, 1, [1]), (1, 1, [1]), (1, 1, [1])],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4', (1,))])
```

'f0' and 'f1' are indexed in the same way; they have the same description (except for name).  `np.dtype` constructor has stripped off or ignored the `()`.

```
In [623]: x['f0']=np.arange(3)
In [624]: x['f1']=np.arange(3)
In [625]: x['f2']=np.arange(3)
....
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (3,1)
```

So the problem, if there is one, isn't with indexing, but with `dtype` ignoring the `()` part of the descriptor.

---

In your first case, the 'd'` field can be accessed with the triple index, or with a 2d index:

```
In [649]: a['d'].shape
Out[649]: (10, 4)
In [650]: a[0]['d'][3]
....
In [651]: a['d'][0,3]
```

My `x['f1']` field with '()' remains 1d

```
In [652]: x['f1'].shape
Out[652]: (3,)
In [653]: x['f2'].shape
Out[653]: (3, 1)
```

I can't think of a meaningful way of creating or indexing a 0d dimension.  We don't want (3,0) shape, and can't have (3,())`shape or`[:,()]` indexing.

Comment: Yup, you got it.